# R loop to return text based on patterns in character string

Tags: r

I have a vector of complex responses such as the following:

```
c(
    '106A+106C+MRSA+RB1',
    'R109+230E+RB3',
    '76TR+RB4',
    'R109+230E+RB3+R71',
    'R109+230E+RB3',
    'R194'
)
```

Some entries have 1 element, some have 4. I need to write a loop that runs through the dataset and returns an answer based on the presence/absence of 'RB1', 'RB3', and 'RB4' and returns a response in a new column...if the string contains 'RB1', I need it to print 'Low', and if it contains 'RB3' or 'RB4', it should print 'High'.

I've messed about with different combinations of strsplit, is.element, and ifelse statements, but can't seem to hit the right combination. I may be punching above my weight as I haven't mastered functions and loops yet, but maybe someone out there can help? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you are looking for is "grepl"

```
x=c("106A+106C+MRSA+RB1","R109+230E+RB3","76TR+RB4","R109+230E+RB3+R71","R109+230E+RB3","R194")

ifelse(grepl("RB1",x),"LOW",ifelse(grepl("RB3",x)|grepl("RB4",x),"HIGH","ERROR"))
```

this should work.
update as suggested by rawr

```
ifelse(grepl("RB1",x),"LOW",ifelse(grepl("RB3|RB4",x),"HIGH","ERROR"))
```

Comment: `grepl('RB3|RB4', x)` would be better or even better `grepl("RB[34]", x)`

Comment: thanks. din't know , you could do this. I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to handle this.  I'd use `grepl` if you've only got 2 conditions:

```
x <- c("106A+106C+MRSA+RB1", "R109+230E+RB3", "76TR+RB4", 
         "R109+230E+RB3+R71", "R109+230E+RB3", "R194")


new <- rep(NA, length(x))

new[grepl("RB1", x)] <- "High"
new[grepl("RB[3-4]", x)] <- "Low"

new
## [1] "High" "Low"  "Low"  "Low"  "Low"  NA
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks great...then what's the next step to create a new column where True = 'Low' and False = 'High'?